# Input in Python

Tags: python, input

I have just started using Python, and I got a problem with non-english (Vietnamese in particularly) input. When I run this code:

```
# -*- coding: unicode-escape -*-
s = raw_input()
print(s)

s = "hiển thị 15 dòng"
print(s)
```

and from terminal I type extracly the same string, it printed like:

```
hiển thị 15 dòng
hi\xe1\xbb\x83n th\xe1\xbb\x8b 15 d\xc3\xb2ng
```

It also make differences in when I use these 2 type of strings in other function as I found the first one didn't work but the second one did.
Would anyone give me some hints?
Thank you!

Comment: Xin chào, I suggest that you save yourself from confusion; if you're a newcomer to Python, you should be using Python 3, which is very mature by now, it has proper Unicode support built in.

Comment: Thanks, but my project forces me to use Python 2.7 :)

Comment: What platform are you on? If you're on Windows, your terminal may not be able to support `print`ing Unicode strings, so even after you fix things (as Raniz's answer shows) you still may not get to see what you want. If you're on any *nix besides Mac OS X, your terminal probably can support Unicode strings, but Python 2 may still not guess the right encoding, causing similar problems…

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I just look at the output when I run it on terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `# -*- coding: unicode-escape -*-` in your source file. It causes python to escape all the bytes greater than 128 in the UTF-8 representation with the `\xnn` hex escape, turning your string into

```
'hi\xe1\xbb\x83n th\xe1\xbb\x8b 15 d\xc3\xb2ng'
```

Thus with `# -*- coding: unicode-escape -*-`:

```
s = "hiển thị 15 dòng"
```

will become

```
s = 'hi\\xe1\\xbb\\x83n th\\xe1\\xbb\\x8b 15 d\\xc3\\xb2ng'
```

---

The cause of course is using `unicode-escape` as a codec for `coding`; use `utf-8` instead:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: By the way what is the default codec of I/O in terminal?

Comment: it will depend on the locale settings; you can see it from the `locale` command ; if your locale is for example `en_US.UTF-8`, or `vi_VN.UTF-8` things should mostly work.

Answer (score 2):

you may try to replace the `# -*- coding: unicode-escape -*-` with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the beginning of the file to specify the encoding of the code file, which depends on your system default file encoding.

Comment: You have to do that, and _also_ do the other fixes Raniz suggested.

Comment: The thing is, if coding is not specified, the Vietnamese text will make the code not *run at all*, so that is not the case.

Comment: It seems strange that `raw_input()` returns a `str` which should be exactly the same as the second `s` below. The first `s` is printed appropriately but the second doesn't.

Comment: Indeed this answer was correct unlike I first thought (and the reason behind that was that the code excerpt was *not* a self-contained example)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're using Python 2.x?

If so, put the following at the top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And ensure that your strings are unicode strings:

```
s = raw_input().decode("utf-8").
print(s)

s = u"hiển thị 15 dòng"
print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added    " # -*- coding: unicode-escape -*- " on the top of the code. 
But what I concern here is that why it makes differences and how to make the first type of input works as the seconde one does :)

Comment: @HưngCaoXuân: Why did you add `unicode-escape` instead of `utf-8`? If you use `unicode-escape`, Python won't be able to handle things like `s = u"hiển thị 15 dòng"` in your code; the only thing that will work will be `s = u"hi\u1ec3n th\u1ecb 15 d\xf2ng"` instead. (And if you really want to write that, it will work even _without_ an encoding declaration.)

Comment: Python 2.x assumes that your source code is in either ASCII or Latin-1 (can't remember which one). When python reads your source file it encounters the byte sequence for your vietnamese characters and tries to read it using the default encoding - resulting in [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: @Raniz: `raw_input` doesn't use the locale at all; it just reads the bytes as bytes, and you have to decide how to `decode` them manually.

Comment: @Raniz: No, not there either; decoding happens in the `.decode('utf-8')` that you explicitly put in your code to fix his problem. :)

Comment: I just removed that entire section =)

If you don't `decode("utf-8")`, you'll print a byte-string which will be decoded by the terminal using the same locale it was encoded with during input. When we `decode("utf-8")` it'll be encoded again before being sent to the terminal.

Comment: @Raniz: Your `s = u"hiển thị 15 dòng"` fix was important too. Putting Unicode text into a `str` literal and just crossing your fingers that the terminal is in the same encoding as your source file (which it usually isn't on Windows) and that Python guesses your terminal's encoding properly (which it usually doesn't on some Linux distros) and so on is not nearly as robust as just using a `unicode` literal (not that that can't _also_ go wrong, but it goes wrong more obviously, like a `UnicodeEncodeError` instead of mojibake…).

Comment: Absolutely, so is to decode your input string if you're actually going to do anything other than just printing it to the same terminal again. I'm just explaining why `print(raw_input())` works without any explicit decoding.

Comment: the problem was using `unicode-escape` as the encoding, it messes up with even 8-bit strings.